# JSON.stringify to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need solution.
Look please:

```
setInterval(function(){
    alert(JSON.stringify(dragposition));
},1000);
```

It works great. It shows me json code.
But I need put json in variable. Something like this:

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(dragposition);
setInterval(function(){
    alert(json_text)
},1000);
```

But it's not working. (Shows `'{{}}'` )
`dragposition` is `ui.position` from jQuery ui.

Comment: If you `console.log(typeof dragposition, dragposition)`, what do you get?

Comment: That means `dragposition` is empty. `{{}}` is probably the correct output. (Although, it's not valid JSON, I wonder where you got that `{{}}`)

Comment: Suggest posting the code that populates dragposition. Maybe put a demo of the problem on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
var json_text;
setInterval(function() { 
  json_text = JSON.stringify(dragposition); 
  alert(json_text);
}, 1000);
```

json_text will be accessible out of the setInterval loop

Comment: @zerkms: the `stringify` is in the interval.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I see that. I meant - what would it change?

Comment: @zerkms: Unless `dragposition` is changing, nothing.

Comment: @zerkms well it change that json_text will be accessible out of the setInterval loop ...

Comment: @solisoft: it is accessible out of the `setInterval` in the original code as well

Comment: @zerkms, yes but if dragposition change, json_text won't change in the original code

Comment: @solisoft: so? How is it related to the question? OP didn't mention something will be modified.

Comment: My understanding is that he need to get fresh json every seconds in an external variable, isn't it?